# A single program for implementing 9 CPU Scheduling Algorithms

Tags: cpu, scheduling

9 CPU Scheduling Algorithms are as follows :-

1. First Come First Serve
2. Shortest Job First (Preemptive)
3. Shortest Job First (Non Preemptive)
4. Longest Job First (Preemptive)
5. Longest Job First (Non Preemptive)
6. Round Robin
7. Priority (Preemptive)
8. Priority (Non Preemptive)
9. Highest Response Ratio Next

For Priority algorithms, anyone will work (highest number = highest priority) or (lowest number = highest priority).

Also user can decide which algorithm to select at run time according to requirement and display its analysis(CT,TAT,WT,RT).

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not really clear to me what your quesiton is, please read [ask]

Comment: Is it clear now ??